# How to pass arguments to subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess

learning python to replace bash here and I've tried to generate an argument and pass it to subprocess.call. Tried a couple of ways but it only ever seems to run the first section.
as an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
command='ls -l'
dibner='scum.py'
commands=[command, dibner]
subprocess.call(commands,shell=True)
```

logically I thought this would call ls -l scum.py but it seems to just call ls -l. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `ls`, `-l` separately.

```
...
command = ['ls', '-l']
dibner = 'scum.py'
commands = comamnd + [dibner]
...
```

Otherwise, `ls -l` instead of `ls` is interpreted as a command.

Comment: I tried this which is pretty much what you said:#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
command=['ls', '-l']
dibner='scum.py'
commands=command + [dibner]
subprocess.call(commands,shell=True)

Comment: @KeefBaker, What do you mean `is only ran ls` ?

Comment: @KeefBaker, Try to remove `shell=True`.

Comment: I also managed to get round it using #!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
dibner = 'scum.py'
command = "ls -l %s" % dibner
subprocess.call(command,shell=True)

Comment: @KeefBaker, If you use string formatting, you should take cae of escaping. For example, think about file names with space, special characters.

Comment: Thanks, so %r would be better?

Comment: @KeefBaker, Instead of using string formatting, pass arguments as a list items and use `shell=False` (not `shell=True`)